# Is it bad to std::iter_swap with a past-the-end iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

I've been using [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) to swap the elements referenced by two iterators. I've just been wondering what the effect of this will be if one of the iterators is the past-the-end iterator, the like of which is returned by `end()`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> is = { 1 };
    cout << "Before: " << is.at(0) << endl; 
    iter_swap(is.begin(), is.end());
    cout << "After:  " << is.at(0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[This code compiles and runs fine.](http://ideone.com/2Mjjl5)

```
Before: 1
After:  0
```

So clearly the `1` has been swapped somewhere, but this seems a bit odd.

1. Where is the `1` now?
2. Where has the `0` come from? Is it a representation of the `end()` iterator? I guess it could also be the default value of an `int` that has default constructed?
3. Is this undefined behaviour, or generally dodgy in some other way? Do I need to take precautions to prevent against doing this?
4. Is this implementation specific? Does this apply for all iterators or just for `vector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `25.3.3 swap` (alg.swap) the effect of `iter_swap` is

> Effects: swap(*a, *b).
>   Requires: a and b shall be dereferenceable. *a shall be swappable with (17.6.3.2) *b.

As it dereferences both iterator, if one of the iterator is past the container, you may not be able to dereference it.

---

> Where is the 1 now?

Possibly past your vector. It may or may lie within the end_of_allocation.

> Where has the 0 come from? Is it a representation of the end() iterator? I > guess it could also be the default value of an int that has default
>   constructed?

It is an uninitialized value and may or may not be 1. Moreover you may observe a memory access error / crash also.

> Is this undefined behaviour, or generally dodgy in some other way? Do I
>   need to take precautions to prevent against doing this?

Yes and yes. Never access memory beyond the allocated block directly or indirectly.

> Is this implementation specific? Does this apply for all iterators or
>   just for vector?
>   Not it is not implementation specific. It is undefined. It applies for all iterators.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is bad. `iter_swat` needs to dereference both iterators, but you may not dereference the iterator returned by `end()`.